# DatagridView Background does not refresh. Traces left behind

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a DataGridView bound on a generic list, in .NET 3.5.

When this grid is resized, there is a residual traces that is left behind on the background of the grid where there is no items. This only occurs where there is some columns that have the WrapMode attribute set to True. It seems that only the content that is wrapped is not refreshed on the background of the grid.

Anybody have a workaround or a resolution for this problem?

Comment: Are you running any worker threads that update the binding source?  You can't.

Comment: No worker thread, and no OnDrawCell... but there is a hook on the RowHeightInfoNeeded, and when I remove it, and manually adjust the height of the rows, the problem is not reproducable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not found any solution for that, i have a workaround by creating a custom form for edition and leave the grid read-only with one-time height adjustment.

Third-party grids should do better for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=VS.80).aspx) method, also set the `.DoubleBuffer` property to `false`. Or you can write [code for custom painting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163669.aspx).

Comment: I tried the Refresh method, and DoubleBuffer property, without success. Is there any alternatives to writing custom painting code for out-of-the-box behavior?

Comment: @Curchy: How about `YourDataGridView.Invalidate();`? and  `YourForm.Invalidate()`.

Comment: Tried that too... as previously mentioned, this problem only occurs when the RowHeightInfoNeeded event is handled... maybe that this could give you a hint.